# How to use Wordpress rest API with Angularjs 4

Tags: rest-api

I am learning AngularJS and wanted to created a project in AngularJS 4. In this I want to use WordPress back-end and get data through rest API. I have done little bit research but not found any useful tutorial or example. I don't want to create theme in WordPress based on AngularJS, but want independent application in AngularJS which only use WordPress rest API for displaying content. I want to know how can i implement Wordpress Rest API in to AngluarJS application.
So tutorial or example in this topic will be great helpful

Comment: How to develop an AngularJS is 1) off topic here 2) too broad for any stack exchage webiste. To read more about WordPress REST API (the only thing on topic here) there's the official documentantion http://v2.wp-api.org/ and then... [Google](https://www.google.it/search?q=WordPress+REST+API+tutorial&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8), I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good starting point if you are new to angularjs and WP Rest API with very brief and well documented code.

https://github.com/michaelbromley/angular-wordpress-seed

Cheers to [Michael Bromley](https://github.com/michaelbromley)

Comment: crap angular1 dont use this

Answer (score 0):

Just install WordPress, the API is enabled by default. You can use the API for posting, editing and deleting content for example. All the API calls you can find in the docs.

http://v2.wp-api.org/

http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/

Comment: that i already know, i want to know how can i implement wordpress API in to Angularjs.  i don't have any idea to call rest API in angularJS application.

Comment: https://github.com/stuartkuentzel/ng-wp-theme